# What is the best way to create numbered tabs using Python and Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been working on the following code, and I would like the tabs created by the program in the application window to be numbered "Frame 1", "Frame 2", etc. Whenever a new tab is added or deleted, however, the tab numbers displayed aren't updated. Also, whenever the "Update Title" button is pressed, the tab which is selected becomes numbered correctly. I am extremely close, but I think I need to move some parts of my code around in order for it to work correctly.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import colorchooser as colorchooser
from tkinter import filedialog as filedialog

class AllColorsApp:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.mainwindow = tk.Tk() if master is None else tk.Toplevel(master)

        self.tabs = {}
        self.frame_count = 1
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.mainwindow)
        self.notebook.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.create_initial_tab()
        self.create_buttons()
        self.create_menu()

        self.mainwindow.bind_all("<Control-s>", lambda event: self.save_config_to_file())

    def create_initial_tab(self):
        initial_frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(initial_frame, text=f"Frame {self.frame_count}: 'Initial Frame'")
        self.create_leds(initial_frame)
        self.tabs[self.frame_count] = (initial_frame, 'Initial Frame', '1.00')

    def create_leds(self, frame):
        for i in range(1, 10):
            led_frame = ttk.Labelframe(frame, text=f"LED {i}")
            led_frame.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

            select_color_button = ttk.Button(led_frame, text='Select Color')
            select_color_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

            canvas = tk.Canvas(led_frame, background="#fb8686", borderwidth=0, height=25, highlightbackground="#c0c0c0", width=25)
            canvas.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

            select_color_button.configure(command=lambda c=canvas, led_num=i: self.choose_color(c, led_num))

    def create_buttons(self):
        top_button_frame = ttk.Frame(self.mainwindow)
        top_button_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=5)

        create_frame_button = ttk.Button(top_button_frame, text="Create Frame", command=self.create_new_frame)
        create_frame_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

        delete_frame_button = ttk.Button(top_button_frame, text="Delete Frame", command=self.delete_selected_frame)
        delete_frame_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

        update_title_button = ttk.Button(top_button_frame, text="Update Title", command=self.update_frame_title)
        update_title_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

        self.title_entry = ttk.Entry(top_button_frame)
        self.title_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

        delay_label = ttk.Label(top_button_frame, text="Delay:")
        delay_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

        self.delay_entry = ttk.Entry(top_button_frame)
        self.delay_entry.insert(0, "1.00")  # Default value
        self.delay_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

    def open_file(self):
            file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files", "*.txt"), ("All files", "*.*")])
            if file_path:
                # Perform actions to open and process the selected file
                print(f"Opened file: {file_path}")
                # Add your file processing logic here

    def create_menu(self):
        menubar = tk.Menu(self.mainwindow)
        self.mainwindow.config(menu=menubar)

        file_menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.open_file)  # Bind the open_file method to "Open" menu item
        file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.save_config_to_file)
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.mainwindow.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

    def choose_color(self, canvas, led_num):
        color_code = colorchooser.askcolor(title="Choose color")[1]
        if color_code:
            canvas.configure(background=color_code)
            # Update the LED color in the respective frame
            self.update_temp_config_color(led_num, color_code)

    def update_temp_config_color(self, led_num, color_code):
        # Update the color in the temporary configuration file or storage as needed
        pass  # Implement this method according to your storage logic

    def update_frame_title(self):
        current_tab = self.notebook.select()
        if current_tab:
            tab_index = self.notebook.index(current_tab)
            new_title = self.title_entry.get()
            new_tab_name = f"Frame {tab_index + 1}: '{new_title}'"  # Adjust index for tab numbering
            self.notebook.tab(current_tab, text=new_tab_name)
            self.tabs[tab_index + 1] = (self.tabs[tab_index + 1][0], new_title, self.tabs[tab_index + 1][2])  # Update title in stored data
            del self.tabs[tab_index]  # Delete old entry
            self.update_frame_numbers()  # Update numbering after title change
            self.renumber_all_frames()  # Renumber GUI tabs

    def update_frame_numbers(self):
        # Update the numbering in the stored data based on the current order
        updated_tabs = {}
        for index, tab in enumerate(self.notebook.tabs(), start=1):
            tab_info = self.tabs[self.notebook.index(tab)]
            updated_tabs[index] = (tab_info[0], tab_info[1], tab_info[2])

        self.tabs = updated_tabs

    def renumber_all_frames(self):
        # Print the list of tabs and renumber the displayed tabs in the GUI without gaps
        index = 1
        for tab in list(self.notebook.tabs()):
            tab_info = self.tabs[self.notebook.index(tab)]
            new_tab_name = f"Frame {index}: '{tab_info[1]}'"
            self.notebook.tab(tab, text=new_tab_name)
            index += 1

    def print_tab_names(self):
        for index, tab in enumerate(self.notebook.tabs(), start=1):
            tab_info = self.tabs[self.notebook.index(tab)]
            print(f"Frame {index}: '{tab_info[1]}'")

    # Update the methods
    def switch_to_tab(self, index):
        self.notebook.select(index - 1)  # Index starts from 0 in the notebook, so subtract 1

    # Update the methods
    def create_new_frame(self):
        self.frame_count = max(self.tabs.keys(), default=0) + 1  # Find the next available index
        new_tab_name = f"Frame {self.frame_count}: 'New Frame'"
        new_frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)

        self.notebook.add(new_frame, text=new_tab_name)
        self.create_leds(new_frame)
        self.tabs[self.frame_count] = (new_frame, 'New Frame', self.delay_entry.get())

        self.update_frame_numbers()  # Update the numbering
        self.renumber_all_frames()  # Renumber all frames after creating a new one
        self.print_tab_names()  # Print tab names after creation
        self.switch_to_tab(self.frame_count)  # Switch to the newly created tab

    def delete_selected_frame(self):
        current_tab = self.notebook.select()
        if current_tab:
            tab_index = self.notebook.index(current_tab)
            self.notebook.forget(tab_index)
            del self.tabs[tab_index]

            # Update numbering and GUI tabs after deletion
            updated_tabs = {}
            for index, tab in enumerate(self.notebook.tabs(), start=1):
                tab_info = self.tabs[self.notebook.index(tab)]
                updated_tabs[index] = (tab_info[0], tab_info[1], tab_info[2])
                new_tab_name = f"Frame {index}: '{tab_info[1]}'"
                self.notebook.tab(tab, text=new_tab_name)

            self.tabs = updated_tabs
            self.print_tab_names()  # Print tab names after deletion

            # Switch to the first tab after deletion if any tabs are left
            if len(self.notebook.tabs()) > 0:
                self.switch_to_tab(1)


    def save_config_to_file(self):
        # Save the configuration to file or storage as needed
        pass  # Implement this method according to your file-saving logic

    def run(self):
        self.mainwindow.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = AllColorsApp()
    app.run()
```

I have been fiddling with the tab system for the past couple of hours, but it seems I've simply been going in circles as northing I try works.

Comment: Instead of counting the tabs created, why don't you create a list of the created tabs and count the elements each time you update it and automatically rename the tabs created?

Comment: "Frame 1", "Frame 2", "Frame 3", "Frame 4" ,"Frame 5", "Frame6". If I delete Frame3, Then select the tab" Frame 4" and press update. It should become" Frame 3".

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @1966bc How do you recommend I automatically update them and rename the tabs created? I have different functions which try to accomplish that, but they don't seem to be functioning correctly

Comment: @toyotaSupra Exactly, but the Update Title button only changes the name of the current frame and its number correctly. I would like to have it so that when a new tab is created or deleted, all of the tabs can be loaded from a list, then repopulated.